# C - Multithreaded WordCount runtime crash -now compile fail: redefinition of struct timespec?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, word-count

I'm working on a multi-threaded word count program for class and I've got it mostly done but, despite successfully compiling with warning tags, my program crashes instantly. So, basically the program is supposed to take a given txt document(which is just text from the book) and split it into 16 threads which individually count the words and the total is summed in main.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
//pthread_cond_t cond;


typedef struct thread_data
{
    int input;
    int offset;
    int size;
    int wordCount;
} thread_data;

void *counter(void *arg)
{
    thread_data *data = (thread_data *)arg;
    char *buffer = malloc(data->size);
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    int isChar = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    lseek(data->input, data->offset, SEEK_SET);
    read(data->input, buffer, data->size);

    for (i = 0; i < data->size; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\t' || buffer[i] =='\n')
        {
        isChar = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isChar == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
            isChar = 1;
        }
    }
    data->wordCount = count;
    free(buffer);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int id;
    int segSize;
    int total;
    //int fileSize;
    pthread_t *threads;
    int input;

    input = open("Assign3.txt", O_RDONLY); //open file

    segSize = lseek(input,0,SEEK_SET)/16;  //Getting segment size for  partition    

    struct thread_data data[16];

    threads = malloc(16*sizeof(pthread_t));

    for(id =0; id < 16; id++)  //Partitioning of file to threads
    {
        data[id].input = input;
        data[id].offset = id*segSize;
    }

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, 0);

    for(id = 0; id < 16; id++)  //create threads
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, &counter, &data[id]);
    }
    for(id = 0; id < 16; id++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[id], NULL);
    }

    for(id = 0; id < 16; id++)  //compute total from threads
    {
        total += data[id].wordCount;
    }

    printf("There are %i words in this document.\n", total);

    //cleanup
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);  
    close(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Previously, this would compile and it would crash when running. I don't think I changed anything, but now when I compile this using MinGW and the command (the first is exactly how my professor will be compiling the code)

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -lpthread Assign3_MichaelMorro.c
//or
gcc -Wall -Werror Assign3_MichaelMorro.c
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from Assign3_MichaelMorro.c:3:0:
c:\mingw\include\pthread.h:320:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'
 struct timespec {
        ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\time.h:53:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\pthread.h:219,
                 from Assign3_MichaelMorro.c:3:
c:\mingw\include\parts\time.h:105:8: note: originally defined here
 struct timespec
        ^
```

How can I deal with this?
Is it possible that doing this on a linux computer with native gcc would work? If anyone is using linux and can try compiling this for me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Use a debugger to help you find the problem. Writing code and compiling it is only the first step. Debugging is a major part of a devs work so you might as well learn to do it now.

Comment: `segSize = lseek((int)input,0,SEEK_SET)/16;`. Is that supposed to use `SEEK_END` instead of `SEEK_SET`?

Comment: I was just about to add that I tried debugging, the error that showed up was just in terms of registers. So, its a memory issue, the only problem is I don't have any clue how to use that information to diagnose the issue. If I was writing this in assembler I might have a chance but I've never learned how to translate register values into meaningful info for c code.

Comment: You're not supposed to silence compiler warnings by adding casts until they go away. You're supposed to understand *why* the compiler is complaining, possibly by *reading the manpages of the functions you use*. I know, it's tough, and you didn't sign up for this, but such is C.

Comment: You hold a mutex while you're doing all the "real work" and every other thread needs to acquire that very same mutex to do any work. That pretty much defeats the point of multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code I get warnings. To me, those warnings seem pretty serious.

```
$  gcc -Wall a.c -o a -lpthread
a.c: In function 'counter':
a.c:28: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
a.c:29: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:65: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

When I look at the lines I see that you are casting `FILE*` to `int`.

That is just plain wrong.

You should replace the `lseek` function call to one that works with `FILE*`, like `fseek`.

Or, if you prefer to use `lseek`/`read` etc you should open the file using `open` which returns a file descriptor (type `int`).

If, for some reason, you don't want to switch to `open()` you can get the file descriptor from `FILE* fp` like this:

```
int file = fileno(fp);
```

Comment: yeah, using fseek would be a lot better, unfortunately one of the requirements is that I use lseek. As for those warnings, I was not getting those, but thank you for posting them. They are most likely the problem, now I just need to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: @Littledude1222 You can use `open` instead of `fopen`. `open` returns a file descriptor which is what the first parameter of `lseek` requires. Unless you are required to use `fopen`.

Comment: @Littledude1222 I've added how to I compile to get warnings (`-Wall` for `gcc`) and a suggestion to use `open()` instead of `fopen()` to open the file to my answer.

Comment: Yeah I was using -Wall it probably wasn't showing because I'm using Mingw to compile. I made the change to open and switched the variable to int, but unfortunately it still crashes.